# [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters

Tags: ansible

I was wondering what is the correct syntax for `when` statements?

I have this playbook:

```yaml
- set_fact:
   sh_vlan_id: "{{ output.response|map(attribute='vlan_id')|list|join(',') }}"

- name: create vlans
  ios_config:
    provider: "{{ provider }}"
    parents: vlan {{ item.id }}
    lines: name {{ item.name }}
    with_items: "{{ vlans }}"
  register: result
  when: '"{{ item.id }}" not in sh_vlan_id'
```

And, running it, gives me a warning but it still runs through. I am not sure if this is correct or not.

```
TASK [set_fact]    ************************************************
ok: [acc_sw_01]

TASK [create vlans] ***********************************************
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: "{{ item.id }}" not in sh_vlan_id

skipping: [acc_sw_01] => (item={u'id': 10, u'name': u'voice-1'}) 
skipping: [acc_sw_01] => (item={u'id': 101, u'name': u'data-2'}) 
skipping: [acc_sw_01] => (item={u'id': 100, u'name': u'data-1'}) 
changed: [acc_sw_01] => (item={u'id': 11, u'name': u'voice-2'})
```

If I remove the curly braces around `item.id` in the `when` statement:

```yaml
when: item.id not in sh_vlan_id
```

It gives me an error:

```
TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************
ok: [acc_sw_01]

TASK [create vlans] ***********************************************
fatal: [acc_sw_01]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'item.id not in sh_vlan_id' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if item.id not in sh_vlan_id %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/ansible/cisco-ansible/config_tasks/vlan.yml': line 16, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: create vlans\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I'm using ansible 2.3.0 (devel cbedc4a12a).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The correct syntax is to not include Jinja delimiters (`{{ ... }}`) as indicated by the warning. Your condition doesn't work otherwise because the types are not compatible.

You could try type coercion:

```yaml
when: 'item.id | string not in sh_vlan_id'
```

See: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#builtin-filters

Comment: Remember that this approach wont work for replacing `{{ item.id }} is defined`.

Comment: How do I do this when I want to replace the item as part of a string?
when: "worker{{ item }}=w{{ item }}pod" not in label_info.stdout

Comment: @Raviteja, my solution is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zkZjWpnt2C/

Comment: Batting zero on these - the link next to See: doesn't work, and the paste.ubuntu.com wants you to have an account to even consider showing you something. :(

Answer (score 7):

Another example for reference ..

```
  - name: Sudoers | update sudoers file and validate
    lineinfile: "dest=/etc/sudoers
      insertafter=EOF
      line='{{ item.username }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
      regexp='^{{ item.username }} .*'
      state=present"
    when: '{{ item.use_sudo }} == True'
    with_items: '{{users}}'
```

I was getting below orning.

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: "{{ item.use_sudo}}" == True
```

After making the below changes into the playbook it works fine.

```
- name: Sudoers | update sudoers file and validate
  lineinfile: "dest=/etc/sudoers
    insertafter=EOF
    line='{{ item.username }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
    regexp='^{{ item.username }} .*'
    state=present"
  when:  'item.use_sudo|bool'
  with_items: '{{users}}'
```

**UPD:** if you use variable  type `boolean` that `== True` not need

Answer (score 1):

Braces must be removed when calling a variable in a when clause.

In this example, we install the urbackup client only if it is not already installed or if the version already present is different from the version contained in the variable.

urbackup_client_version is a variable defined in the playbook:

```
vars:
  - urbackup_client_version: 2.5.22
```

then we check in a role if urbackup is already installed.

```
- name: Is UrBackup already installed?
  shell: urbackupclientctl --version
  register: urbackup_enable 
  failed_when: urbackup_enable.rc != 1 and urbackup_enable.rc != 127
```

It is necessary to position the variable with braces in the wget command but you have to remove them in the when clause:

```
- name: UrBackup client installation
  shell: 'TF=$(mktemp) && wget "https://hndl.urbackup.org/Client/latest/UrBackup%20Client%20Linux%20{{urbackup_client_version}}.sh" -O $TF && sudo sh $TF; rm -f $TF'
  when:
    - action == 'install'
    - urbackup_enable.rc == 127 or (urbackup_enable.rc == 1 and urbackup_client_version not in urbackup_enable.stdout)
```