# ansible when conditional statement - warning about jinja2 templating delimiters

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

So I'm using this ansible playbook:

```
 # Check if /backup folder is mounted
 - name: "Check if /backup folder is mounted"
   command: /bin/mountpoint {{ do_backup_folder }}
   register: mount_status
   failed_when: false
   changed_when: false
   tags: ['digitalocean', 'spaces', 'mount']

 # Mount digitalocean spaces to /backup
 - name: "Mount digitalocean spaces to /backup as {{ litecoin_user }} user"
    shell: |
     s3fs {{ do_spaces_name }} {{ do_backup_folder }}  -o url={{ do_spaces_url  }} -o use_cache=/tmp -o allow_other -o use_path_request_style -o nonempty -o uid={{ getent_passwd.litecoin[1] }} -o gid={{   getent_passwd.litecoin[1] }}
   when: mount_status.stdout == "{{ do_backup_folder }} is not a mountpoint"
   tags: ['digitalocean', 'spaces', 'mount']
```

where **do_backup_folder** is defined in group_vars as /backup.

The playbook runs just fine but when running I'm getting this:

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: mount_status.stdout == "{{ do_backup_folder }} is not a mountpoint"
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: mount_status.stdout == "{{ do_backup_folder }} is not a mountpoint"
```

How should I rewrite that when condition to get rid of this warning? I've tried in several ways but it's not working. I want to use the `{{ do_backup_folder }}` variable in the when condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ansible - when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673045/ansible-when-statements-should-not-include-jinja2-templating-delimiters)

Comment: It should but I was not able to make it work according to that post. That's the reason I've decided to ask again a similar question. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Is not quite the same thing since here I'm comparing the out of a registered vars with an string formed from the value of a defined variable + a text message...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a `when:` context, the whole thing is implicitly in `{{ ... }}` which is why they whine about subsequent uses of `{{` -- it's a grave antipattern to have nested jinja2 mustaches.

For the same reason one did not need to wrap `mount_status.stdout` in mustaches, nor does one have to wrap `do_backup_folder` in them. The only subsequent decision is whether to use `+` or `~` (the former being the pythonic operator, the latter being the [jinja2 string concat operator](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators) and would be employed when one wished the argument to be coerced into a string)

```yaml
 - name: "Mount digitalocean spaces to /backup as {{ litecoin_user }} user"
   shell: |
     s3fs {{ do_spaces_name }} {{ do_backup_folder }}  -o url={{ do_spaces_url  }} -o use_cache=/tmp -o allow_other -o use_path_request_style -o nonempty -o uid={{ getent_passwd.litecoin[1] }} -o gid={{   getent_passwd.litecoin[1] }}
   when: mount_status.stdout == do_backup_folder + " is not a mountpoint"
   tags: ['digitalocean', 'spaces', 'mount']
```